# What shoud I do/know before send my first ios app to Apple App store?

Tags: ios, app-store, submit

What shoud I do/know before I'll send my first ios app to Apple App store? Thak you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Test the App
- Let others test your App (try to find people with different devices and iOS versions)
- Check the official guidelines and make sure your App does not use private API's

And, most important: be patient, review may take more time than expected.

Answer (score 1):

Be ready to wait. Patience is a virtue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow official documented guidelines and you will be unlikely to encounter any problems. 99% of bad stories you've heard about the app submission process are from people who didn't.